# Running macchanger in Kali Linux VM Disables Network Connection

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-adapter, kali-linux, mac-address

Below is my version of kali which is a vm running on VBox 5.2.22:

```
Linux kali 4.18.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2kali1 (2018-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As the title says, after changing my mac address my network disconnects and I can't reconnect to the network.

Before executing a pen test I'd like to spoof my address (I know there are other things that has to be done but spoofing my mac address has been giving me issues).

I have looked at a couple of articles as to why my internet connection cuts after I change my mac address [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131539/spoofed-mac-address-with-macchanger-but-cant-connect-to-internet) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347884/no-internet-after-using-macchanger-linux-mint-18) but to no avail do those work.

I have read that the setting on Network at the top right overrides the mac spoofing command in the terminal.

I have tried setting the cloned address to the new mac address below:

[image]

Did a network restart and still nothing. Has anyone been successful at changing the mac address on a Kali VM running on virtualbox?

Can this not be done in a VM?

Comment: Can you provide the steps you took to 'spoof' your mac address? Perhaps something is going wrong with your method.

Comment: This user also had issues spoofing their MAC when running Kali on a VM: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?37395-Trouble-with-mac-changing-in-kali-running-on-VM

Comment: Hey Michael. Yes, I actually seen that article including the others in the link provided. I had trouble downloading the zip file as well from the kali forums. As for what commands I was running: ifconfig eth0 down>macchanger -r eth0>ifconfig eth0 up. Also tried a combination of things with network manager but to no avail.

Comment: I'm wondering if I will just have to dual boot kali onto my laptop and then test to see if it works rather than going the vm route.

Comment: Tried what you suggested on going to VBox network settings and it works. It makes sense that that's the only way that it would work.

Comment: The switch has to allow your MAC to change as it decides what IP maps to what MAC in the ARP table. In this case, your switch is a virtual switch. The MAC address is not visible outside of the virtual environment. Devices on the physical LAN will see the communication coming from the MAC of the HOST machine.

Comment: To expand on @HackSlash: What you are trying to do won't allow you to "spoof" your MAC address, and it's a consequence of running Kali in a VM (which isn't a good idea, even though apparently more and more people are doing it). Kali is really made for penetration testing: you put in on an USB stick, not in a VM. To learn Linux and "hacking", a standard distro in a VM is much easier to use (and has all the hacking tools Kali has, though you may need to install them).

Answer (score 1):

When you use VBOX you don't need to use Mac changer. Change the address directly from the configuration of VM BOX.